# How to Preserve Line Breaks in Text Extracted with pytesseract?

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract

I'm using `pytesseract` to extract text from an image, and I want to preserve line breaks in the output. For example, in the provided screenshot, I'd like to capture text in the format `[100, "", "", 200]` and `["", "", 100, "", 200]`, but my current output only shows `[100, 200]`, and I've even tried using the `preserve_line_breaks` option without success.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Here is what I tried:

```
custom_config = '--oem 3 --psm 6 preserve_line_breaks'

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, config=custom_config)
```

I've experimented with different configurations, including the preserve_line_breaks option, but I can't seem to retain the desired output with line breaks.